# exportar reportes.jasper(ireport) en formato excel

Tags: java, excel, jsp, jasper-reports, ireport

No he podido encontrar la solución para poder exportar un reporte a excel. 
Logre exportarlo en formato pdf en un proyecto web dinámico en eclipse.

```
    File reportfile = new File (application.getRealPath("empleado.jasper"));

    Map<String,Object> parameter = new HashMap<String,Object>();

    String valor1 = request.getParameter("txtparametro1");
    parameter.put("valo",new String(valor1));
    String valor2 = request.getParameter("txtparametro2");
    parameter.put("valor",new String(valor2));

    byte[] bytes = JasperRunManager.runReportToPdf(reportfile.getPath(), parameter,con);

    response.setContentType("application/pdf");
    response.setContentLength(bytes.length);
    ServletOutputStream outputstream = response.getOutputStream();
    outputstream.write(bytes,0,bytes.length);

    outputstream.flush();
    outputstream.close();
    %>
```

Todo lo anterior incluyendo la conexión están hechos dentro del WEB-INF en archivos .jsp y quisiera que la exportacion en excel tambien este en un .jsp.

Alguien que me pueda ayudar, se los agradecería mucho.

Comment: El código que presentas permite exportar tu reporte de Jasper a PDF. Debería ser muy similar para exportar a Excel. ¿Qué problema tienes exactamente?

Comment: Que no se como implementarlo para exportar en excel

Comment: En lugar de `JasperRunManager` usa `JasperFillManager.fillReport()' para crear un objeto `JasperPrint` el cual pasarás a un `JRXlsExporter` o `JRXlsxExporter`, dependiendo de la versión de la librería que usas.

Answer (score 1):

Pondré mi ejemplo para generar un Excel desde una aplicación web, sería similar para tu caso:

```
jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reportePath, parametros, conn);

// Mostrando el documento
httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResponse();
ServletOutputStream servletOutputStream = httpServletResponse.getOutputStream();
httpServletResponse.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + nombreReporte + ".xls");
httpServletResponse.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
//httpServletResponse.setContentLength(arrayOutputStream.toByteArray().length);

JRXlsExporter exporterXLS = new JRXlsExporter();

exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, servletOutputStream);
exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_ONE_PAGE_PER_SHEET, Boolean.FALSE);
exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_DETECT_CELL_TYPE, Boolean.TRUE);
exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_WHITE_PAGE_BACKGROUND, Boolean.FALSE);
exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_REMOVE_EMPTY_SPACE_BETWEEN_ROWS, Boolean.TRUE);
exporterXLS.exportReport();

FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();
```